# Translation Job Unknown Tag Error

Tags: sdl-tridion, translation-manager, sites-9, xml

I am have a workflow set up that sends bundles of components out for translation. Once they are translated, they get sent back to us for a review where we can either approve, reject, or continue to revise the translation job. It has all been working great, but Now as we send some components out to get translated again, a Version. 2 of the component, only some of the translation jobs are succeeding. For instance if I send one component out to get translated in many languages, 4 of them will succeed and one or two will fail.

This is the message I am receiving each time one of them fails:

```
Translation Job id: 124
Translation Job title: Test Home WF_2 components_1 lang v.2
Translation management system job id:XXXXXXXXXX__124_20211208011149
Source Publication URI: tcm:0-4-1
Source Publication title: 020 Global Content

unknown tag {urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}mrk

   at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.TranslationSystems.SdlXliffDocument.ParseMrkElement(XElement element, IList`1 resultTextPartsList)
   at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.TranslationSystems.SdlXliffDocument.ExtractSegments(XElement elementWithSegments, String transUnitId, List`1 xliffSegments)
   at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.TranslationSystems.SdlXliffDocument.ExtractSegmentsFromTranslationUnit(XElement transUnitElement, XName elementName)
   at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.TranslationSystems.SdlXliffDocument.GetTextSegments(Dictionary`2 xliffElementLookup)
   at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.TranslationSystems.SdlXliffDocument.GetTextSegments()
   at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.TranslationSystems.TmsTranslationSystemItem.RetrieveTextSegments()
   at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.Service.RetrieveFromTranslationTask.RetrieveItem(TranslationSystemItem item, TmsTranslationJob tmsJob, IList`1 errorPublicationUris, RetrieveReason retrieveReason)
   at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.Service.RetrieveFromTranslationTask.RetrieveItems(TmsTranslationJob tmsJob, IEnumerable`1 jobStatus, IList`1 errorPublicationUris)
```

Comment: Can you clarify the statement "but Now as we send some components out to get translated again, a Version. 2 of the component, only some of the translation jobs are succeeding.". What;'s the significance of "Version. 2 of" ... the sentence is a little confusing and may distort the actual message you're trying to convey. Is it..
"It has all been working great, but now *reject* some components to get translated again - resulting in a new version of the component, only some of the translation jobs are succeeding.

Comment: What version of TM you use?

Answer (score 1):

This ended up being a bug with Sites failing to parse Xliff with comments that had been added during the workflow, which makes sense why it was only happening to Version 2+ documents/ components. Also incase anyone finds this in the future here is the article that explains it a little better and says there is a hotfix.

[Items with comments added in TMS fail to retrieve in SDL Tridion Sites 8.5/9.1](https://gateway.sdl.com/communityknowledge?articleName=000011383)

Answer (score 0):

What translation services are setup - I'm presuming this isn't World Server?

So if you send a translation job with components 1,2,3 and 4 in.
Get the review option and reject component 2.

1. What is observed?
2. Does component 2 fail or other components
3. what are you seeing in the event system logs (with DEBUG)?

Comment: So in that case Component 2 would only be rejected and the others would still be Assigned, Started Activities, etc. The error I included in the question was really the only hint as to what was going on too. However I ended up finding that it was a bug with Sites failing to parse XLIFF with comments that had been added during the workflow, and there is a hotfix for it.